# Use of Logical Operator in Loop Condition

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, do-while, logical-operators

In the below given code, why the `||` logical doesn't work, instead the loop terminates specifically when `&&` is used ?

```cpp
int main() {
    char select {};
    do {
        cout<<"Continue the loop or else quit ? (Y/Q): ";
        cin>>select;
    } while (select != 'q' && select != 'Q'); // <--- why || (or) doesn't work here ??
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `||` would make it always be true. Think about it. It must always be not equal to *one* of them.

Comment: It works exactly as expected.

Comment: Consider this simple question: Is `'q'` equivalent with `'Q'` ? No , it isn't Therefore, if `select != 'q'` were *false*, that means `select == 'q'` must be true. But then wouldn't `select != 'Q'` definitely be *true* (since `'q' != 'Q'`) ? And vice versa ? The result is, using `||` in that context guarantees an always-true overall expression. In fact, a decent compiler will *warn* you of as-much.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I wasn't trying to be snarky. Did my comment come off that way?

Comment: @FredLarson no, not at all. I'm admittedly the laureate of snarky, believe me. was actually trying not to be; you're fine.

Comment: Read up on [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). When I have trouble understanding a complicated loop condition, I find it sometimes helpful to calculate the converse so I can see what the conditions would have to be for the loop to end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This loop will go on while `select` is not `q` **and** it's not `Q`:

```
while (select != 'q' && select != 'Q');
```

This loop will go on while `select` is not `q` **or** it's not `Q`.

```
while (select != 'q' || select != 'Q');
```

Since one of them *must* be true, it'll go on forever.

Examples:

1. The user inputs `q`

`select != 'q'` evaluates to `false`
`select != 'Q'` evaluates to `true`
`false || true` evaluates to `true`

2. The user inputs `Q`

`select != 'q'` evaluates to `true`
`select != 'Q'` evaluates to `false`
`true || false` evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 2):

You want to terminate the loop when select is equal either to `'q'` or `'Q'`.

The opposite condition can be written like

```
do {
    cout<<"Continue the loop or else quit ? (Y/Q): ";
    cin>>select;
} while ( not ( select == 'q' || select == 'Q' ) );
```

If to open the parentheses then you will get

```
do {
    cout<<"Continue the loop or else quit ? (Y/Q): ";
    cin>>select;
} while ( not( select == 'q' ) && not ( select == 'Q' ) );
```

that in turn is equivalent to

```
do {
    cout<<"Continue the loop or else quit ? (Y/Q): ";
    cin>>select;
} while ( select != 'q' && select != 'Q' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following diagrams:

[image]

The full ellipse are all characters. The white dots is `q` and `Q` respectively. The black filled area depicts characters that will make the expression `true`. First line is `select != 'q' && select != 'Q'`, second line is `select != 'q' || select != 'Q'`.

`&&` means both conditions must be `true`. The resulting black area is the overlap of the two areas on the left.

`||` means either of the conditions must be `true`. The resulting black area is the sum of the two areas on the left.

Comment: Awesome example ! Thanks user:4117728 